# How to deny user access to Paginator sort?

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to prevent user accessing sort:field url if I use paginator? I want deny sorting because I got millions of rows and it's really slow sorting unindexed fields.

Comment: do you really need to be paginating *millions* of records? See [here](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2011/03/17/speed-up-your-pagination-with-a-simple-hack/) for one option

Comment: Funny, because I just tried that at work today. It was actually just what I needed but using paginateCount on your model won't work if you don't have custom paginate function also at the same model. Or thats what I thought after some time trying. And managed to speed up my count(*) query. But please share if you know how to use it without custom paginate -function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the paginator link in the view. So instead of `<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name');?></th>` just use `<th>Name</th>`

The users can still sort by name, but as long as it's not a security issue, it's fine.

If you really need to prevent sorting on particular columns, or allow only on some columns, filter `$this->params['url']` and `$this->passedArgs` (you have to remove from both of them)

Comment: We can count on you Anh Pham, again. Removing paginator links was pretty obvius but thank you for pointing out params & passedArgs.